# URL to ping Postgres DB to check uptime

Tags: postgresql

We have set up a series of uptime checks on all of our online services.

The last one is our Postgres DB. Given the connection URL in the format of:

```
postgres://username:password@domain-name:port/restriction
```

Does postgres comes out of the box with an http-callable url that would return a `200` if DB is up and `500` or nothing is DB is down?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use pg_isready to check the connection status of a PostgreSQL server

```
pg_isready --dbname=dbname --host=hostname --port=port --username=username
```

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pg-isready.html):

> pg_isready returns 0 to the shell if the server is accepting
>   connections normally, 1 if the server is rejecting connections (for
>   example during startup), 2 if there was no response to the connection
>   attempt, and 3 if no attempt was made (for example due to invalid
>   parameters).

Comment: What is dbname? Why is hostname not enough?

Comment: @Soren My guess would be that not all dbs are available at the same time once the server starts. Also, --dbname can be used to specify a connection string.

Comment: I figured you do not need the db name to check if the database is running.

Comment: I'm not sure this command does what it claims to do. I've tried it with random database names, and random usernames, and it always says connection works

Answer (score 4):

No, it does not speak HTTP. You'd have to talk to the database using its driver software or make a small web service that does nothing but ping the database on demand.